# Extracting images from a black background

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a few objects in a black background.I would like to threshold the image and transform the objects in 1 and the black background into 0.
I am not sure how to choose my threshold to isolate the black background.

Comment: Right now your question isn't specific enough for people to give good answers. What have you tried? Can you post an example image and give a better description of what results you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by the following step.

1. Load your image.
2. Convert to gray-scale.
3. Apply [binary threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#threshold-binary) which will create the result as your requirement.

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) you can see a good explanation about Basic Thresholding Operations using OpenCV with example.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest thing to do is using the OpenCV's [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) function on the whole image and let the threshold value be choosen automatically by means of the [Otsu's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) (the `type` argument of the threshold function should be ORed with the constant `THRESH_OTSU`).

Otsu's original work is: OTSU, Nobuyuki. A threshold selection method from gray-level histograms. *Automatica*, 1975, 11.285-296: 23-27.

This approach may work very well or it may fail miserably... it depends, as always, on your images.